# Sort by key and value, Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hash sorted by value, but I want to print keys in lexicographical order if keys have same frequency.

My code:

```
sorted_terms_list = new_array.sort_by {|key, val| val}.reverse
```

For example input:

`{'a': 1, 'abortion': 1, 'aaron': 1, 'aaa': 1, 'ab': 1, 'aa': 1}`

Expected output:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaron
ab
abortion
```

Comment: You need to state the print order of two keys with different values. I assume it is to be the key with the lower value, but it needs to be stated.  In that regard, the hash values in your example should not have all been equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what return the sort method.

> The block must implement a comparison between a and b, and return -1,
>   when a follows b, 0 when a and b are equivalent, or +1 if b follows a.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-sort

```
hash = {'ab' => 2, 'abortion' => 6, 'a' => 2}
hash.to_a.sort{|a, b| (b.last > a.last) ? 1 : (b.last < a.last ? -1 : (a.first <=> b.first)) }
#=> [["abortion", 6], ["a", 2], ["ab", 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way :-

```
hash = {'a' => 1, 'abortion' =>  1, 'aaron' => 1, 'aaa' => 1, 'ab' => 1, 'aa' => 1}
puts hash.sort_by { |k,v| [v,k] }.map(&:first)

# >> a
# >> aa
# >> aaa
# >> aaron
# >> ab
# >> abortion
```

Comment: @pertpoert With your input the expected output should be `["a", "aa", "aaa", "aaron", "ab", "aberdeen", "able", "abortion", "abraham", "absence"]`, considering the _frequencies are same for all keys_.

Answer (score 0):

Only `hash.keys.sort` will do this.

```
hash = {'a' => 1, 'abortion' =>  1, 'aaron' => 1, 'aaa' => 1, 'ab' => 1, 'aa' => 1}
sorted_terms_list = hash.keys.sort
puts  sorted_terms_list
```

This will give you desired output

Comment: If `hash => {:a=>2, :b=>1}`, I believe the required result is `puts ['b', 'a']`.  Because you disregard the values, you get `puts ['a', 'b']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts new_array.sort_by(&:reverse).keys
```